# Как убрать глюк в NumberPicker?

Tags: java, android

У меня в программе три авторских NumberPicker в ряд. Они прекрасно работают. Но при открытии программы в первом NumberPicker появляется буква "Б", которой даже нет в его массиве. Я всё проверила и не понимаю, откуда она взялась. Помогите, пожалуйста, если у вас есть хоть какие-то предположения на эту тему.

Основная активность:

```
                private MyNumberPicker myNumberPicker;

                private MyNumberPicker2 myNumberPicker2;

                private MyNumberPicker3 myNumberPicker3;

    private TextView tvNumber,tvResult;

  //Позиция (int) в массиве

                int pos,pos2,pos3;

                 //Создадим массивы значений

                //Для размера шрифта

    final String[] values = {"12", "14", "16", "20"};

    //Для жирного и нормального шрифта

    final String[] values2 = {"В", "N", "B", "N"};

    //Для цвета шрифта

    final String[] values3 = {"Б", "Ч", "К", "С","Ж","З"};

    @Override

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

       

        myNumberPicker = (MyNumberPicker) findViewById

                               (R.id.my_number_picker);

        myNumberPicker2 = (MyNumberPicker2) findViewById

                               (R.id.my_number_picker2);

        myNumberPicker3 = (MyNumberPicker3) findViewById

                               (R.id.my_number_picker3);

       

        tvNumber= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.hnp_tv_number);    

        tvResult= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_result);

       //Изменяем цвет фона

        myNumberPicker2.setBackgroundColor(Color.YELLOW);

       
        myNumberPicker.setInitialValue(0);

        myNumberPicker.setMinValue(0);

        myNumberPicker.setMaxValue(values.length-1);

       

        myNumberPicker2.setInitialValue(0);

        myNumberPicker2.setMinValue(0);

        myNumberPicker2.setMaxValue(values2.length-1);

       

        myNumberPicker3.setInitialValue(0);

        myNumberPicker3.setMinValue(0);

        myNumberPicker3.setMaxValue(values3.length-1);

       /*

        //Задаём значения, которые будут отображаться в numberPicker.

        myNumberPicker.setDisplayedValues(values);

        myNumberPicker2.setDisplayedValues(values2);

        myNumberPicker3.setDisplayedValues(values3);

        */

        //Устанавливаем, должно ли отображаться первое число,

        //как только мы достигнем конца.

        myNumberPicker.setWrapSelectorWheel(true);

        myNumberPicker2.setWrapSelectorWheel(true);

        myNumberPicker3.setWrapSelectorWheel(true); 

        //Получить позицию из NumberPicker

        pos=myNumberPicker.getValue();

        pos2=myNumberPicker2.getValue();

        pos3=myNumberPicker3.getValue();

       

      //Изменяем значение tvResult                      

                if(pos<=values.length-1)

                tvResult.setText(values[pos]);                                

                if(pos2<=values2.length-1)

                tvResult.setText(values2[pos2]);         

                if(pos3<=values3.length-1)

                tvResult.setText(values3[pos3]);

    }

}
```

А это макет NumberPicker. У меня все три счётчика с одним макетом, но с разными, но аналогичными классами.

```
<merge xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <RelativeLayout

        android:layout_width="80dp"

        android:layout_height="80dp"

        android:background="#CCCCCC00"

        >

      

        <TextView

            android:id="@+id/hnp_tv_number"

            android:layout_width="wrap_content"

            android:layout_height="wrap_content"

            android:layout_centerVertical="true"

            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"

            android:textSize="30dp"

            android:textStyle="bold"

            android:layout_marginRight="4dp"

            android:textColor="#CCCCCC00"

            />

        <TextView

            android:id="@+id/tv_result"

            android:layout_width="wrap_content"

            android:layout_height="wrap_content"

            android:text=""

            android:textSize="30dp"

            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"

            />

       

    </RelativeLayout>

</merge>
```

Слушатели в классах счётчиков аналогичные:

```
//Создаём слушатель для TextView

                //При нажатии текста значение меняется на следующую цифру

                    tvNumber.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                       

                                               @Override

                        public void onClick(View view) {

                                //При нажатии выводим следующую цифру

                             setValue(getValue()+1);

                            //Если цифра равна макс значению+1,

                            //выводим минимальное значение

                            if(getValue()==getMaxValue()+1)

                                setValue(getMinValue());

                           

                          //Получить позицию из NumberPicker              

                            pos=getValue();             

                           //Изменяем значение tvResult                                 

                                if(pos<=values.length-1)

                                tvResult.setText(values[pos]);                                

                        }

                    });
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Приведите код классов `MyNumberPicker`, `MyNumberPicker2`, `MyNumberPicker3`.

Comment: Извините, но это сложно. Код у меня компьютере, а я в планшете. Но я привела слушатель оттуда. Ничего больше там не может повлиять на мой глюк. Там кроме слушателя только один из массивов, инфляттер, три конструктора, геттеры и сеттеры, пара методов для отображения значений и для зацикливания счётчика. Всё работает прекрасно.

Comment: Без кода можно только строить предположения.  Например, есть ли у вас наследование между классами и хранятся ли у вас массивы как статические поля?

Comment: Между этими классами счётчиков у меня нет наследования. Они все наследуют ЛинеарЛаоут как и положено. Массивы у меня в классах в том же виде, как и в МайнАктивити. Т.е. не хранятся как статические поля.А зачем их хранить как статические поля?

Comment: Как, по-вашему, можно увидеть ошибки в коде не видя самого кода? Очень похоже на то, что у вас вьюшки с текстом накладываются друг на друга из-за неверных привязок в макете.

Comment: Но макет здесь есть и Вы его можете увидеть. Что в нём неправильно? И почему второй и третий счётчики не глючат, а первый глючит, если макет у них один? И что такое "вьюшки с текстом"? Я специально разместила один TextView на другом и получила именно тот внешний вид, который мне нужен. А просвечивает нижний TextView только потому, что мне так удобнее работать с кодом. Какое это имеет отношение к заданному мною вопросу?

Comment: Я не вижу весь ваш проект - откуда мне знать что имеет отношение к проблеме, а что нет... Макет пикера я вижу, но макет активности и что к чему относится на снимке экрана - нет, и как оно должно выглядеть по вашей задумке мне неизвестно. Если у вас все три пикера разом на экране с одинаковым макетом, то `tv_result` присутствует в макете активности трижды, но вы получаете только одну ссылку на первый попавшийся и вставляете в него значения из всех трёх массивов - отображается то, что вставлено последним.

Comment: Сегодня вечером я доберусь до компьютера и скину код.

Comment: Но в макете активности у меня только лаоут и три пикера. По моей задумке оно должно выглядеть как на первой картинке и именно так и выглядит. И ссылку на конкретный массив для конкретного счётчика я получаю не одну, а три. Именно для этого у меня три отдельных класса счётчика, и в каждом свой инфляттер и свой массив, и поэтому каждый счётчик - это экземпляр разного класса. И это понятно из МайнАктивити.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В `pos3` у вас что при инициализации? Правильно, `0`.

А последняя операция в `onCreate()` какая?

```
if(pos3<=values3.length-1)

            tvResult.setText(values3[pos3]);
```

Условие выполняется? Конечно, вот вам `Б`.

**Дополнение:**
когда вы ищете компонент разметки таким способом, и их у вас несколько с одним и тем же ID (tv_result)

```
tvResult= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_result);
```

То система найдет первый попавшийся в иерархии (из первого пикера).

Не видя всей разметки предположу что надо искать вот так:

```
tvResult = (TextView) myNumberPicker3.findViewById(R.id.tv_result);
```

Это для третьего, первый и второй соответственно.

Comment: Спасибо, но, извините, можно поподробнее? Я думала, что в этой операции используется tvResult из соответствующего pos,pos2 или pos3 счётчика. Если нет, то мне нужно либо как-то указать, из какого счётчика tvResult, либо просто создать по макету для каждого NumberPicher?

Comment: Добавил подробностей.

Comment: Большое спасибо, я попробую.

Comment: Большое спасибо, всё получилось.